# How to create user-defined tasks in Debian?

Tags: debian, package-management

According to the Debian terminology, a task is a collection of several individual Debian packages all related to a specific activity (see [here](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/ch-pkgtools.en.html)). Tasks can be installed through the `tasksel` program (usually during the system installation).

I would like to create my own tasks. For example I want to create a task called "type setting" in which I can put all the packages I need for type setting (say TeX, LaTeX, ...). Or, as another example, I want to have a "web dev" task, etc. This would greatly simplify the installation of new systems and package management in general.

How can I create user-defined tasks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Task descriptions are stored in `/usr/share/tasksel/descs`

The format of task descriptions is explained in `/usr/share/doc/tasksel/README.gz`

> The file format is a rfc-822 style stanza, with fields named Task, Section
>   Description (which should include an extended description), Key, Packages, 
>   Enhances, Test-, Relevance, and Parent fields.

Here is an example of a description

```
Task: graphical-games
Relevance: 9
Parent: games
Section: user
Description: Graphical games
 This task provides a variety of graphical games. Old-school unix games are
 not included.
Key:
 x-window-system-core
Packages: list
 quake
 myst
 monkey-island
```

For more details read `/usr/share/doc/tasksel/README.gz`